# Jenkins(Hudson) SVN checkout dir

Tags: svn, jenkins, svn-checkout

In Jenkins (Hudson) how do i change the checkout location of a project.

I want the project to be checked out to the doc-root of apache2 which is  at `/var/svn/project`
by default Jenkins checks it out to the `/jobs` dir on `/lib/jenkins/`

I thought of running a shell command to copy the checked out code from jobs folder to the doc-root but it'll copy the entire folder even if its a single file that has been changed.

Should i look in to rsync or can Jenkins do this (even with a plugin)

Comment: So it sounds like you want your Jenkins job to deploy to your Apache server?

Comment: yep. using the ftp plugin i managed to get it to deploy on our remote server but i cant get it to update the code on the local server. apache and jenkins and svn are all on the same server

Comment: Sounds like you should move Jenkins off so you can just use the FTP plugin also. However, you should be able to use the job scripts to get the same effect I would imagine. Our jobs use scp to move files from the Jenkins workspace to where we need them.

Comment: hmmm i tried rsync but it gives me and error 
rsync: link_stat "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/SVN Update - Local/workspace.
im guessing this is because of the spaces and the - on my path.

Comment: I ended up dong this 

rsync -auv ./ /var/svn/project/base/

which seem to work

Comment: Congrats. Make your last comment the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 9):

There is an option in Jenkins to change the location of your workspace...

On the job configuration page, under the section "Advanced Project Options", click the "Advanced" button.

Check the box near "Use custom workspace", and fill in the location where you want your check-out to go.

Comment: My scripts are there in the custom build workspace.. But I want to checkout in separate dir ? it says absolute path is not allowed. How can I do that ?

Comment: Jenkins will always check out to your workspace - whether it is the default, or a custom workspace. I'm not sure what you mean by your scripts are in the workspace but you want to check out to a different area.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option for this in the Jenkins SVN plugin.
I was, however, able to achieve it on Windows with a directory Junction Link - and you could do the same on a *nix installation with a symbolic link.

Specifically, I cd'ed into the Jenkins job/myjob/workspace directory and did this

```
mklink /J junction_to_working_copy c:\my\real\working\copy
```

then in the Subversion configuration of the Jenkins project (under Source Code Management) for the "Local module directory (optional)" field I entered:

```
junction_to_working_copy
```

This does the trick well enough